# Entity : Common property - Finding a sport played by all the students

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I would like find a common property that appears in all the models.

I currently have two model classes `Student` and `Sport`. A student can play multiple sports. 
I would like to find all sports that are played by all the students.

This is what my models look like

```
public class DbContext : DbContext
{
        public DbContext(): base("name=DbContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Student> MyStudents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sport> MySports { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public List<Sport> Actions { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Sport
{
    public string SportName { get; set; }
}
```

My question is how do I get a list of all sports played by all the students? In short I am looking for common sports. So basically in the following case

```
Student A played Sports : Soccer , Tennis , Bowling
Student B played Sports : Soccer , Tennis , 
Student C played Sport  : Tennis
```

Then only Tennis should be returned and only once (Not multiple Tennis Instances).
This is what I did

```
var sports = context.Sports;
var commonSports = sports.Where(sport =>
    students.All(student => student.Actions.Any(studSport => 
         studSport.SportName == sport.SportName)));
```

However the above yields multiple results. I.e. Multiple Tennis and not just one.
Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: What type is `sports` (is it a `List<Sport>`?) and how do you initialize it?

Comment: let me update that

Comment: @JohnWu just updated it

Comment: Any chance `sports` has duplicates in it? You can eliminate them with `Disctinct()` but it would be nice to know if there is an issue with your data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SelectMany` to flattens the return lists of sports, and `Disctinct` to avoid duplicates.

```
var commonSports = students.SelectMany(x => x.Actions).Distinct();
```